# How to make a file with the same name as another txt file,without overwriting the file but instead add a number to the existing one in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

Example:

```
while True:
 file = open("example.txt", "w")
 strings = ["Hello","World"]
 file.writelines(string)
```

I want each iteration to make a new file with names example1.txt example2.txt etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
counter=1
while True:
   filename = "example" + str(counter) + ".txt"
   with open(filename, "w") as file:
       strings = ["Hello","World"]
       file.writelines(string)
   counter+=1
```

Note that in your code you're not closing the file, but using `with` will take care of that for you.

EDIT:

To check which `.txt` filenames are already in a given directory, you can use `glob`:

```
import glob
filenames = [file for file in glob.glob('/some/directory/*.txt')]
```

Assuming you only have files like `example{counter}.txt`, the last element will have the biggest counter, which you can then extract:

```
last_filename = filenames[-1]
counter = int(last_filename .split('.')[0][-1])
```

Comment: add a break condition

Comment: See i was thinking this too,but wouldnt running the programme multiple times overwrite the last files,since the counter always starts at 1,how can i make the counter start at the last file number,i guess my question is can you read the names of text files in a folder somehow to gather the last number.

Comment: @Rishabh I'm merely modifying the OP's code which has no break condition.

Comment: @Kima in that case you need to look into the directory for the latest value of `counter` and start from there.

Comment: @PApostol can you point me to a direction,how can i access filenames from a directory through code?

Comment: @Kima23 please modify the question for that purpose. And bring more clarity to your requirements. And also, your code needs a break condition :)

Comment: @Kima23 see edit. I agree with Rishabh about the suggestions :)

Comment: @Rishabh Kumar Hey man,i'm sorry it's my first time using this forum to ask questions,i'll get better at understanding the rules as time goes on and formulating questions is a bit hard for me since english isn't my main langague

Comment: @Kima23 no problem, if you're satisfied by the solution please mark it as the accepted answer as per Stack Overflow guidelines.